# How to use XSLT 2.0 in SharePoint

Tags: 2013, xslt

How do I use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) 2.0 in SharePoint? Do I need to install some package on the server to make it work? Or is it available by default, and I just start using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint only supports Version 1.0 of XSLT. As far as I know, there's no way to update it and there are now changes in newer SharePoint-Versions. More information about this can be found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5727818f-72b3-4476-b255-8ff2b6d22b2c/xslt-and-xpath-20-supported-in-spd-2007-and-moss-2007